# Positioning a div within a div using Jquery and aligning the inner div left

Tags: jquery

I am trying to write a jquery function that moves a div within a div (possibly using Flexbox), I say Flexbox but I am not sure if this is the right way to go.

Background:

I have an image as a css background and I want to display text in front of the image with the ability to click on a button to either align left, align right or align center with in the parent div.

What I have so far:

HTML:

```
<input name="ClientName"  id="client_name" type="text" />


<div id="AlignLeft">
    <input type="image" src="../../../nav/images/align_left.png" name="AlignLeft" id="AlignLeft" value="1" />
</div>
```

And for my Jquery:

```
$('#AlignCenter').click(function() {
    $('#ClientNametext').animate({
        $('#ClientNametext').css('display', 'block') {
            $("#ClientNametext").css({
                margin-left: 5});
        }
    });
});
```

How can I get this to work and should I be looking at using "Flexbox".

Many thanks for your time.

My updated jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#AlignLeft').click(function() {
   $('#ClientNametext').animate({'display': 'block','margin-left': 5});
});

$('#AlignCenter').click(function() {
   $('#ClientNametext').animate({'display': 'block','margin-right': 'auto', 'margin-left': 'auto'});
});

 $('#AlignRight').click(function() {
   $('#ClientNametext').animate({'display': 'block','margin-right': 5});
});


});
```

AlignLeft works but AlignCenter and AlignRight do not. Any ideas why?

Comment: you seem to have extra brackets after the first css.  Also, you are using animate wrong - you should be animating the object in the selector, not passing in another 2 selectors with css

Comment: @Pete can you point out where please

Comment: Check with this:

$('#AlignCenter').on("click",function() {
    $('#ClientNametext').animate({'display': 'block','margin-left': 5},1000);        
});

Comment: @Mayank Nimje that works fine, thanks. I have used the same structure for a "AlignCenter" and "AlignRight" but they do not work. I must be does this wrong, Could you please advise. I have added updated code above.

Comment: Sorry, went to lunch. Mayek, pretty much has done what I was on about.  not sure you can animate margin to auto, think you would need to work out the `(width of the screen - the width of the div) / 2` and margin left that amount and then for align right it would be margin left `width of screen - (width of box + 5)`

Comment: Also why do you need to animate the display? do they not start as block elements?

Comment: @Pete Thaks for your reply. I am working on it to try and make it work. I have removed the "animate" and replaced it with "css". Animate was just a nice to have but not important. I will let you know how I get on. Again, thanks.

Comment: Can't do it with classes as you can't transition margin auto, but here is a quick mock up of the initial problem: https://jsfiddle.net/d4Lyzd01/

Comment: @Pete What a star you are. Many thanks for your time. I will ow try and use your code in my project. Again Pete, many thanks.

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help :)

Comment: @Pete I just upvoted the wrong solution and now it won't let me change it, sorry.

Comment: hahaha, no worries - you don't get anything for upvoted comments